# How to add one Button to multiple Canvasses?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, drawing

I want to create an application with a screen like that depicted below.

```
|-----------------------------------------|
| MainWindow                     [-][=][x]|
|-----------------------------------------|
|                     |                   |
|   (Button1)         |     (Button1)     |
|                     |                   |
|                    1|                  2|
|-----------------------------------------|
|                     |                   |
|   (Button1)         |     (Button1)     |
|                     |                   |
|                    3|                  4|
|-----------------------------------------|

Legend: It a window form has four canvas (are 1,2,3,4) added to grid.
```

Below is my code. I am using .Net 3.0, but the window does not display correctly. Button1 displays only on canvas1. **Please help me to fix this problem.**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button bt1 = new Button() 
        { Content = "Button1", Width = 100, Height = 50 };

        // Add button1 to four DrawingCanvas.
        canvas1.Add(bt1);
        canvas2.Add(bt1);
        canvas3.Add(bt1);
        canvas4.Add(bt1);
    }
}

public class DrawIngCanvas : Canvas
{
    public void Add(UIElement data)
    {
        DrawIngCanvas cv = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(data) as DrawIngCanvas;
        if (cv != null)
        {
            cv.RemoveLogicalChild(data);
            cv.RemoveVisualChild(data);
        }
        base.Children.Add(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered wrapping the button and canvas into a composite control?

Comment: If you don't want too many controls, and want to synchronize all 4 canvas, then you use imaging (`VisualBrush`) to display same copy of 1 main canvas in 2,3,4.

Answer (score 2):

Each `Visual` may only have one `VisualParent`. The button cannot be added to multiple canvases because of this. You will need a separate instance of `Button` for each canvas.

If you want the buttons to each act the same, consider using a `Style`.

Comment: I wants synchronize four canvas. I don't want create new canvas content. Because if number of canvas is so much the data mus be create new is so big. Can you give me detail instruction.

Comment: If you are worried about too many controls being created, you may want to look into UI Virtualization. So that controls are only created for those canvases which are currently visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display one button in four different places you need four buttons.

like so:

```
canvas1.Add(new Button{ Content = "Button1", Width = 100, Height = 50 });
canvas2.Add(new Button{ Content = "Button1", Width = 100, Height = 50 });
canvas3.Add(new Button{ Content = "Button1", Width = 100, Height = 50 });
canvas4.Add(new Button{ Content = "Button1", Width = 100, Height = 50 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple parents of one control, so trying to add `bt1` to `canvas1`, `canvas2`, `canvas3` *and* `canvas4` is never going to work.

Instead, if you want to simulate having the same button in four `Canvas` controls, you need to create four `Button` objects with the same property values (such as `Content` and `Width`), then add them to the `Canvas` controls respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Clone() function ta make exact copy